# Get all unique values out of strings

Tags: c#, .net, string

I am facing some problems while getting *unique values* out of `string`s.

Example:

```
string1 = "4,5"
string2 = "7,9"
string3 = "4,7,6,1"
string4 = "1"
```

After I need to get *all unique values* as an `int`. In this case result must be **6**. But each time the number of strings *can change*.

Is this even possible?

Comment: What did you mean by `unique value` ?

Comment: do some research on `linq` and `distinct`

Comment: He probably means _distinct_ values.

Comment: No I guess OP want value where `occurrence is one`

Comment: OP wants to get a `distinct` list of numbers i believe - ie no duplicates

Comment: Hi @Edgars. Welcome to stack overflow.

One tip for your next question: include (if relevant) any code, even wrong, that you wrote to try to solve your issue.

Sometimes we believe that the issue is in one area, when in fact it is elsewhere. Seeing the code can give some more context and help us guide you to the solution.

In the present case, the problem is simple enough that it was maybe not necessary.

Hope you have a good time and see you again (maybe on the answering side).

Answer (score 3):

Use `Split` and `Distinct`

```
var  input = "1,3,1,2,3,43,23,54,3,4";

var result input.Split(',')
                .Distinct();    

Console.WriteLine(string.Join(",",result));
```

**Output**

```
1,3,2,43,23,54,4
```

[**Full Demo Here**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/fNMurP)

---

**Additional Resources**

[String.Split Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.split?view=netframework-4.7.2)

> Returns a string array that contains the substrings in this instance
>   that are delimited by elements of a specified string or Unicode
>   character array.

[Enumerable.Distinct Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.distinct?view=netframework-4.7.2)

> Returns distinct elements from a sequence.

Comment: @JohnB OCD indeed :)

Answer (score 3):

If "number of strings *can change*", let's organize them into a *collection*:

```
List<string> strings = new List<string> {
  "4,5",
  "7,9",  
  "4,7,6,1",
  "1"
};
```

Then we can right a simple *Linq*:

```
var uniques = strings
  .SelectMany(item => item.Split(',')) // split each item and flatten the result
  .Select(item => int.Parse(item))
  .Distinct()
  .ToArray(); // let's have an array of distinct items: {4, 5, 7, 9, 6, 1}
```

If you want to obtain items which appears *just once*:

```
var uniques = strings
  .SelectMany(item => item.Split(',')) // split each item and flatten the result
  .Select(item => int.Parse(item))
  .GroupBy(item => item) 
  .Where(item => item.Count() == 1)
  .Select(group => group.Key)
  .ToArray(); // let's have an array of items which appear once: {5, 9, 6}
```

Comment: I like this approach upvote, also i need to use my upvotes for the day

Comment: Last one is awesome,+1

Answer (score 0):

1. Instead of using number of string variable you can you single instance of `StringBuilder`
2. Convert all element to array of integer.
3. Get Distinct/number which comes only one once by Linq

Something like this:

```
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.Append("5,5");
    sb.Append(",");
    sb.Append("7,9");
    sb.Append(",");
    sb.Append("4,7,6,1");
    sb.Append(",");
    sb.Append("1"); 

    string[] arr = sb.ToString().Split(',');
    int[] test = Array.ConvertAll(arr, s => int.Parse(s));


    var count = test
        .GroupBy(e => e)
        .Where(e => e.Count() == 1)
        .Select(e => e.First()).ToList();

output: 

9
4
6
```

POC: [.netFiddler](https://dotnetfiddle.net/IY5YVc)

Answer (score 0):

A single line can do the job

```
    string s = "1,3,1,2,3,43,23,54,3,4";
    string[] StrArry = s.Split(',');

    int[] IntArry = Array.ConvertAll(StrArry, int.Parse).Distinct().ToArray();
```

output

`1,3,2,43,23,54,4`

Answer (score 0):

He can you try this out

```
var string1 = "4,5";
var string2 = "7,9";
var string3 = "4,7,6,1";
var string4 = "1";

var allStrings = string1 + ',' + string2 + ',' + string3 + ','+ string4;
var distinctNumbers = new List<string>(allStrings.Split(',').Distinct());
```

Output :
  4
  5
  7
  9
  6
  1

distinctNumbers = Count = 6

Answer (score 0):

This is a longer one than the others, but it might be easier to understand how it works.

```
        List<string> str = new List<string> {"1", "3", "1", "2", "3", "43", "23", "54", "3"," "4 };

        List<string> foundstr = new List<string> { };

        foreach (string check in str)
        {
            bool found = false;
            //going through every single item in the list and checking if it is found in there
            for (int i = 0; i < foundstr.Count; i++)
            {
            //if found then make found(bool) true so we don't put it in the list
                if(check == foundstr[i])
                {
                    found = true;
                }  
            }
            //checking if the string has been found and if not then add to list
            if(found == false)
            {
                foundstr.Add(check);
            }
        }

        foreach(string strings in foundstr)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(strings);
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
```